# How can you fax a document programmatically from within an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, fax

I'd like to be able to fax a document from within my iPhone application.  Is there a third-party API or sample code available that can do this?

Comment: iPhone doesn't have a fax modem built in. There is no API.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and fastest way to do this would be to use a eMail to Fax service like MaxEMail. Then, just use the well established mailto: URL to launch the iPhone mail application with your fax contents. If this doesn't meet your needs, please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Third party app doesn't have access to the telephony services on the iPhone.  You will have to implement a third-party solution provider that utilize the internet.